# Why is this simple hello world code segfaulting?

Tags: c

Excuse the beginner level of this question.  I have the following simple code, but it does not seem to run.  It gets a segmentation fault.  If I replace the pointer with a simple call to the actual variable, it runs fine... I'm not sure why.

```
struct node
{
 int x;
 struct node *left;
 struct node *right;
};

int main()
{
 struct node *root;
 root->x = 42;
 printf("Hello world. %d", root->x);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct node *root;
root->x = 42;
```

You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. To allocate storage for the node:

```
struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You could also allocate a node on the stack:

```
struct node root;
root.x = 42;
```

Comment: So I should prefix it with some kind of initialization?  struct node *root = new (struct node); or something?

Comment: In this particular case I would declare a `struct node root` rather than a pointer and then use `root.x` and pass `&root` to functions that expect a pointer. Not always is dynamic storage justified.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a pointer to access something, the pointer must be pointing at that something. In order for the pointer to be pointing at that something, that something must exist. Creating a pointer does not create anything for it to point at. You must do so explicitly, either by dynamic allocation (`malloc()`), stack allocation (i.e. a local variable) or by pointing to something that already exists (e.g. a `static` instance, such as a global; a value that was passed in as a parameter; etc.).

Answer (score -1):

After `struct node *root;` line add the

```
root = (sturct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Also, before `Return 0` line add the

```
free(root);
```